# Python chat application using tkinter. Mainloop problem

Tags: python, class, tkinter, chat

I tried to write a chat application using tkinter and python 3. I would like to combine the functionality of the Server class, which allows to communicate with others, with graphical user interface contained in the GUI class.

The problem is, that with different approaches I end up with the mainloop() function blocking other functionalities. Could you please help me to spot the mistake?

I tried to use a thread to run the `mainloop()`, to use `update()` method instead of it, and to place the `mainloop()` inside a class and make one class inherit from the other.

My level of programming is beginner and any advice about the good practice of building such applications would be appreciated :)

```
import socket
import time
import threading
from tkinter import *

# ------------GUI--------------------

class GUI:

    message = ''
    name = ''

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()

        self.label_1 = Label(self.root, text="Name")
        self.entry_1 = Entry(self.root)  # Input field to get the server name
        self.button_connect = Button(self.root, text="Run server", command=self.retrieve_input)
        self.label_1 = Label(self.root, text="Name")

        self.label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
        self.entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.button_connect.grid(columnspan=2)

        self.receivebox = Text(self.root, height=10, width=40)
        self.writebox = Text(self.root, height=1, width=40)
        self.sendbutton = Button(self.root, text="Send", command=self.display(self.message))

        self.sendbutton.bind("<Button-3>", self.display(self.message))

        self.receivebox.grid(row=4, sticky=E, columnspan=6)
        self.writebox.grid(row=5, sticky=E, columnspan=6)
        self.sendbutton.grid(row=6, sticky=E, columnspan=6)

        gui = threading.Thread(target=self.root.mainloop())
        gui.daemon = True
        gui.start()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def retrieve_input(self):
        self.name = self.entry_1.get()  # Has a name of the user
        print(self.name)

    def display(self, text):
        print("I am a display method")
        self.receivebox.insert(END, text)

#------------SERVER--------------------

class Server(GUI):

    def __init__(self, startpanel):

        self.startpanel = startpanel

        self.s = socket.socket()
        self.host = socket.gethostname()
        self.port = 9999
        self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.s.listen(1)
        self.conn, self.addr = self.s.accept()

        sender = threading.Thread(target=self.send_message)
        sender.daemon = True
        sender.start()

        receiver = threading.Thread(target=self.recieve_message)
        receiver.daemon = True
        receiver.start()

    def receive_message(self):
        incoming_message = self.conn.recv(1024)
        incoming_message = incoming_message.decode()
        return incoming_message

    def send_message(self):
        message = input(str(">>"))
        message = message.encode()
        self.conn.send(message)
        return message

    def return_host(self):
        print("return host working")
        return self.host

def main():

    interface = GUI()
    server = Server(interface)

    server.return_host()

    while 1:
        str(server.interface.display(server.send_message()))
        str(server.interface.display(server.receive_message()))

main()
```

Comment: TCP is es streaming protocol. You cannot use `recv` for messages. You have to built another protocol for messages on top of TCP.

Comment: You must not call `mainloop` in `__init__`, since it never returns.

Comment: Using a Thread to run Tkinter is not a good idea. Also this line is wrong `threading.Thread(target=self.root.mainloop())`  You don't use `()` in a Thread just the callback function